# MYSQL Display results even if count is 0 from one table

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Im trying to get the count to display 0 if the count is 0 for example

Curent results:

```
Extension    Calls
1234         1
1345         2
```

But i want it to display:

```
Extension    Calls
1234         1
1245         0
1345         2

SELECT c.Extension,count(c.Extension),0 as Calls 
from call c
where c.callType=3 
and (c.StartTime between TIMESTAMP(CURDATE(),'06:30:00') and TIMESTAMP(CURDATE(),'07:00:00'))
group by c.Extension
```

Comment: Is you have an extensions table, select from that, `LEFT JOIN calls` on Extension, and you have your result.

Comment: Is `Calls` NULL for Extension=1245?

Comment: this data is all from one table

Comment: What is the value in the Calls field where the extension is 1245? Is it null?

Comment: i think this problem is not with the sql query but maybe they are not actually displayed

Comment: Post the relevant content of `CALL` table.

Comment: @user2133771 Please answer the question two of us asked.  When `Extension = 1245`, is `Calls` NULL, or does `Extension = 1245` appear in the table at all?

Comment: @user2133771 - Why do you think that **1245** should be on the output list?

Comment: its null for all values, i figured it out it the extension only gets added to that table when a call is made therefore it cant show 0 or the extension as it doesn't know it. ill have ti join anther table with the full list of extensions. thank you all for your help

Answer (score 2):

First query in the union is already available in the question where the extensions which have calls of given time and occured in given time are coming. Second query is just a negation of that where the number of calls is taken as zero.

```
        SELECT c.Extension,count(c.Extension) as Calls 
        from call c
        where c.callType=3 
        and (c.StartTime between TIMESTAMP(CURDATE(),'06:30:00') and TIMESTAMP(CURDATE(),'07:00:00'))
        group by c.Extension
    union
        SELECT c.Extension,0 as Calls 
        from call c
        where (c.callType=3 
            and (c.StartTime between TIMESTAMP(CURDATE(),'06:30:00') and TIMESTAMP(CURDATE(),'07:00:00'))) = false
        group by c.Extension
    order by Extension
```

Comment: Little explanation would be great so the OP has some learning experience. Thanks :]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    A.Extension,
    IFNULL(B.ExtensionCount,0) Calls
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Extension
    FROM call WHERE callType=3 AND
    StartTime BETWEEN TIMESTAMP(CURDATE(),'06:30:00')
    AND TIMESTAMP(CURDATE(),'07:00:00')
) A
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT Extension,COUNT(1) ExtensionCount
    FROM call WHERE callType=3 AND
    StartTime BETWEEN TIMESTAMP(CURDATE(),'06:30:00')
    AND TIMESTAMP(CURDATE(),'07:00:00')
    GROUP BY Extension
) B
USING (Extension);
```

Please make sure you have these indexes

```
ALTER TABLE call ADD INDEX
callType_StartTime_Extension_ndx (callType,StartTime,Extension);
ALTER TABLE call ADD INDEX Extension_ndx (Extension);
```

That way, the query does not read from the table. It will read everything from the index.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT c.Extension,
       sum(case when c.callType=3 and
                     c.StartTime between TIMESTAMP(CURDATE(),'06:30:00') and TIMESTAMP(CURDATE(),'07:00:00')
                then 1
                else 0
           end) as calls
from call c
group by c.Extension
```